# How do I embed Gecko using gecko-sharp on Mono/Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, gecko

Gecko is the rendering engine for Firefox. Using gecko-sharp it is possible to embed it to any Mono/GTK# program. There is a sample application called [GladeSharpBrowser](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/Glade-Sharp_and_Gecko-Sharp) for doing this. I could manage to build it using a modified project file, but it is crashing. This sould help you reproduce the problem:

I have used [SharpDevelop 3.0](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/) and a [tutorial](http://mono.wikia.com/wiki/Using_Mono_with_SharpDevelop_3.0) to set it up with my [Mono 2.2](ftp://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/archive/2.2/windows-installer/5/mono-2.2-gtksharp-2.12.7-win32-5.exe) installation. I have made sure it calls Mono's gmcs for compilation using ProcMon. After setting up SharpDevelop, the [BrowserSharp.csproj](http://ifile.it/qlvy67d) had to be modified so it compiles with Mono.

There is also a warning message:

> Found conflicts between different
>   versions of the same dependent
>   assembly.

This is strange, since all the assemblies are the ones provided by Mono.

Sure, there are other methods like GeckoFX, but I am specifically interested in doing it in a platform independent manner using Mono.

Answer (score 2):

Whats probably a better answer to your cross-compatibility issue is the Mono.WebBrowser, as it could be engine independent eventually.

http://www.mono-project.com/WebBrowser

Answer (score 1):

The first step to solving your problem is to figure out why it's crashing.  After building BrowserSharp according to your instructions (although I recreated the csproj separately), I ran:

```
mono --debug BrowserSharp.exe
```

With the --debug flag, mono will print out any unhandled exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: 
An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gecko.WebControl --->
System.DllNotFoundException: gtkembedmoz.dll   
   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gecko.WebControl:gtk_moz_embed_get_type ()
   ...
```

I couldn't find gtkembedmoz.dll in the Mono distribution, but it appears to be a separate install.  A download link can be found [here](http://zbowling.com/projects/gtkembedmoz/), and some old but possibly useful instructions [here](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/14918.html).

I downloaded the stable GRE package and copied the gtkembedmoz.dll into the build directory.  It still crashed, so I checked the dependencies using [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) which made it clear that it was missing the Gtk+ libs.  After installing the [gtk-sharp](http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/gtk-sharp/) runtime and copying the missing dlls into the build directory I managed to get it to run using the Microsoft .NET runtime.

For some reason it still didn't work using Mono.  I suspect there is some difference in how Mono searches for unmanaged DLLs, but I haven't looked into this.  Regardless of whether you use Mono of Microsoft.NET you probably shouldn't need to copy these DLLs into the build directory, it's just a matter of ensuring they're installed/configured properly so they'll be found.