# GTK# multiplatform html widget like gtkhtml#

Tags: c#, html, gtk#

I'm trying to display some text with html markup in GTK#. `gtkhtml-sharp.dll` is perfect for me but I need some functionality on Win32 platform too, any experience with gtkhtml on windows? I search the web but found only trouble with this.
I also try `Mono.WebBrowser` without success - some access violation occured (win) or crash (lin) in native code ocurred; or control not displayed at all.
Another gecko or xulrunner bindings failed as well, I recompile every library and whole mono but withou success.
Webkit is huge for me, that's reason why I don't try `Webkit#` so deep.

Have somebody any idea or suggestion?

Thanks Pavel

Answer (score 0):

From your report it wasn't clear to me if you know about/tried [GeckoSharp](http://www.mono-project.com/GeckoSharp)
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478611/how-do-i-embed-gecko-using-gecko-sharp-on-mono-windows) is about the very same subject.

Edit: If you want help with your errors so far - you should provide more information on them. :)